# Displaying the row/s that correspond the age range condition

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have a sample 2 tables. One is **Scholar** with column **date of birth** and **Scholarship** table. What am I creating here is a criteria by getting the age range. Using the condition **Age_from** and **Age_to**. I want to get/display the row/s that found within the range. What might be the mistake of this code since the return is always empty.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

**database Scholar**

```
scholar_id      Date_of_birth           Ship_level  
1               1991-12-19              Tertiary
2               1990-01-19              Secondary
3               2008-03-19              Primary
4               1992-21-19              Tertiary
5               1991-12-19              Tertiary
6               2000-10-12              Secondary
7               2001-12-23              Secondary
8               2009-12-19              Primary
```

**database Scholarship**

```
ship_id     Age_from  Age_to    Level
1           10        16        Primary
```

**my code**

```
    public function ListOrgaScholar($ship_id)
    {
        $ship = Scholarship::find($ship_id);

        $Agefrom = $ship->Age_from;
        $Ageto   = $ship->Age_to;
        $Level   = $ship->Level;


        $scholars = (new Scholar)->newQuery()->select('*');
        if($Level)
            $scholars->where('Level', '=', $Level);

        $birthDates = $scholars->selectRaw('Date_of_birth');    
        $ag = [];
        foreach($birthDates as $birthDatee){
            list($m,$d,$y)=explode('-',$birthDatee->Date_of_birth);
            $age = Carbon::createFromDate($m,$d,$y)->age;
            array_push($ag,$age);
        }
        $scholars = $scholars->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
//use Carbon\Carbon; - import Carbon in your class/controller

public function ListOrgaScholar($ship_id)
{
    $ship = Scholarship::find($ship_id);


    $fromDate = Carbon::now()->subYears($ship->Age_from)->format('Y-m-d');
    $endDate = Carbon::now()->subYears($ship->Age_to)->format('Y-m-d');

    $scholars = Scholar::where('Ship_level', $ship->Level)
                ->whereBetween('Date_of_birth', [$fromDate, $toDate])
                ->get();        

}
```